# Sharepoint 2010 - How to create a reports with multiple filters, such as a user usage report

Tags: sharepoint

I am looking at creating some reports using the available analytics in SharePoint 2010. I have admin rights for the site and it's sub-sites.

Looking at the available options, there are useful reports that you can use:

- Top pages
- Top vistors
- Number of daily unique visitors

These are all useful, however I need more. What I need to be able to do is:

1) Create user based report that details all the URL's that a visitor has accessed.

2) Create a report that shows top pages visited, but have the abailable to remove certain users (the admin users that are on there all the time, which doesn't provide a true reflection of the figures)

Looking at this, in the analyze tab > change settings, there is only really one option within the filter, like 'visitor contains'. I was hoping that there would be multiple filters that I could apply?

Is there a way I can the above 2 options in SharePoint 2010 via the 'Site Collection Web Analytics reports'?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint 2010 analytics is a bit limited.
It will collect lot's of information, but there is no out of the box functionality to display/analyze all the data.

You'd either create your own solution or look for a 3rd parity. 
A good starting point is CardioLog, it has a free version and might provide you with some insights on what SharePoint 2010 analytics should look like.